# Can force to open page in Reminder with URI when showing in notification

Tags: windows-phone-7

For reminder that created by ScheduledActionService, it wil be displayed by notification when the time is due. 
However, I notice this problem:
1. the Uri in the reminder wont fire and tranfer you to the Page indicated by the URI IF this reminder got displayed when you open this app which created this reminder.

I want to know 
1)it is possible to force open the page indicated in the URI of the reminder? 
2) Override the Click event of the Uri or message area or whatever to do some task?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MilkBottle,

This is very interesting .. good find! The click action on the Reminder cannot be overriden. Trying a few things here ..

Answer (score 0):

> the Uri in the reminder wont fire and tranfer you to the Page indicated by the URI IF this reminder got displayed when you open this app which created this reminder.

Intended behaviour. It's the same for all notifications and toasts, they won't do in-app redirection, if you already have the app open.

> it is possible to force open the page indicated in the URI of the reminder?

Not if you already have the app open. But now why would you want to do that in the first place? If you already have the app open, the user should already be aware of the information, the notification/toast otherwise would point to.

> Override the Click event of the Uri or message area or whatever to do some task?

Not possible.

Comment: Claus - I see what you're saying; but the user could be in a completely different part of the application. Wish there was a way to take them to the intended URI while within the app.

Comment: The problem with doing that, is that it would effectively restart the app, and as such, kill the back-stack. That's why you can't do it while having the application open.

Comment: Yup. Although, if the implementation supported it, the app did not have to restart, rather just navigate maintaining backstack. But yes, moot point!